# Not clear definition in Wasserman book

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm reading the book: [All of statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441923225), by Wasserman, and I think the author wasn't very clear in the definition of the Wald's test on page 153:

> **10.3 Definition.** The Wald Test
>
> Consider testing
>
> $H_0:\theta = \theta_0\ \text{versus}\ H_1 : \theta = \theta_ 0$
>
> Assume that $\hat{\theta}\ \text{is asymptotically Normal:}$
>
> $\frac{\hat\theta-\theta_0}{\hat {se}}\xrightarrow{(d)} \mathcal
>  N(0,1)$
>
> The size $\alpha$ Wald test is: reject $H_0$ when
> $|W|>z_{\alpha/2}$ where
>
> $W=\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_0}{\hat{se}}$

The author shouldn't have write:

> **10.3 Definition.** The Wald Test
>
> Consider testing
>
> $H_0:\theta = \theta_0\ \text{versus}\ H_1 : \theta = \theta_ 0$
>
> **If $H_0$ is true**, assume that $\hat{\theta}\ \text{is asymptotically Normal:}$
>
> $\frac{\hat\theta-\theta_0}{\hat {se}}\xrightarrow{(d)} \mathcal
>  N(0,1)$
>
> The size $\alpha$ Wald test is: reject $H_0$ when
> $|W|>z_{\alpha/2}$ where
>
> $W=\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_0}{\hat{se}}$

I'm a little confused

Comment: Yes, the analysis is assuming the null hypothesis is true. I guess the author did not write it explicitly, since this is how one usually analyzes tests of a given size (significance level).

Comment: @angryavian It makes sense, thank you very much for your help.